# Form in custom template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms

I want to create a form in my custom template like http://nimb.ws/YL2oVp.

Is there any Magento 2 extension exist or i have to build it manually if it so then how to manage dynamic country and region drop downs.

I am beginner at back end Magento 2 kindly guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check my Answer, If it helps you give upvote and click accept to mark green , to help others.

Comment: Is there any free extension i am using magento 2.2.2

Comment: No, I dont think there are free extensions for M2. Still you can check on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few of them by using them you can create dynamic forms as per your need.

https://amasty.com/custom-form-for-magento-2.html

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-form-builder.html

http://mageme.com/magento2-form-builder-extension.html

you can visit these references.
Hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way - after you read about extension architecture - just use `https://mage2gen.com/` which will help you with generating models, forms, grids and more.